# Live reload css with just browser?

Tags: browser, refresh

Is it possible to live reload CSS (so when a CSS file is edited the styles automatically update in the browser) with just the browser? For some reason I often have issues setting up livereload.com and the browser bookmarks dont seem to work anymore.

I thought that Chrome once had this feature but I cant seem to find it now.

Ive also heard that firefox can refresh CSS every x seconds.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Well my problem is that I want the CSS to auto refresh in the browser when a file changes. However the normal solution of live reload (adding a js file to the page or using that particular browser add on) has proved unreliable and problematic for me time and time again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe you can do this on chrome if you load up the developer tools and set up the workspace under the settings tab.

This may help : 
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces

incidentally I use sublime text and emmet livestyle to achieve the same thing :

http://livestyle.emmet.io/

Comment: The chrome linked looked promising. However it only takes affect when ive selected the browser. If I have the browser running but Im working in the text editor the changes arnt updated.

Comment: That's the only issue with it. The sublime and emmet plugin allow you to edit in sublime and see your changes updated but it also works the other way too. If you make a change in developer tools it is reflected in sublime. The only issue I've had is that sometimes when you have particularly invalid CSS it requires you to refresh but it doesn't happen often

Answer (score 0):

A little clunky but this page has a bookmark that refreshes the CSS every 2 seconds http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/100-useful-bookmarklets-for-better-productivity-ultimate-list/